# Create 3 DIV with changing background if mouseover or active

Tags: html, css, background, mouseover

I'm creating an HTML module where I need to display 3 vertically aligned `<div>` with black border, white background and black font color. Each `<div>` has a link inside.

I would like to make this: When I move the mouse over that `<div>`, the background become black, and if the link inside is active, the background of the `<div>` is black (only of the `<div>` with the active link inside).

Is that possible? How can I create this? Now, I only have the `<div>` structure.

Comment: please show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning IDs to each div? You could try something like:

```
<div id="box1">
    <a href="http://www.example.com">Click Here</a>
</div>
<div id="box2">
    <a href="http://www.example.com">Click Here</a>
</div>
<div id="box3">
    <a href="http://www.example.com">Click Here</a>
</div>
```

With styling like

```
#box1 {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border:2px solid #000;
}
#box1 a {
    color:#000;
}
```

If you want the background to change when you hover over the div, use:

```
#box1:hover {
    background-color:#000;
}
 #box1:hover a {
    color:#FFF;
}
```

and if you want it to just do this when you hover over the link do the same as what I just wrote but change #box1:hover to #box1 a:hover

Hope that helps

Comment: Thankyou so much for your fast and clear answer. This is what i need but i also would make a different background for tha div where the link is active.

So if i click on div box1 i would that while i'm on that page, the background of box1 si different. And so on for the other div.

Is that possible?

Thankyou for your help :)

Comment: Hi, i tried to make something like:

#box1:active a {}

also tried:

#box1 a:active {}
but nothing appens...could you let me know how to change css proprieters for the div with the active link? :(

Thankyou again.